# How to express action (in plays, and online)

Tags: colloquial-language, orthography

So in most languages we can either put text in italics or between asterisks to indicate what the speaker is doing. For instance:

*Looking up*
It will be raining soon

Or on the Internet:

*chewing your tacos* can i borrow food from you?

Is there any equivalent forms in Japanese?

Answer (score 1):

You can just enclose the action with parentheses. For example, "*Looking up* It will be raining soon" will be （見上げながら）雨が降りそうだ。Note that full-width parentheses（）looks nicer than normal parentheses () in Japanese sentence.